# what does query(class1).join(class2) do?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I created a `User` and `Address` class and populated it with some data: 3 users, 6 addresses, first user has 1 address, second user has 2 addresses, and the third user has 3 addresses.

If I do

```
q = session.query(User).join(Address).all()
```

I see the generated SQL as

```
SELECT user... FROM users JOIN addresses ON users.id = addresses.user_id;
```

as expected. However, I expected 6 rows when I print `q` but I only get 3, namely the 3 users.

If I issue out the SQL inside sqlite3, I get my 6 rows.

So, what does `query(class1).join(class2)` do?  Looks like an inner join but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have also `JOIN` on `Address` will only change the `WHERE` clause, so it will not return those `Users` who do not have any addresses. And, even those the SQL query returns 6 rows, since you asked [`query(User)`] only for Users, it will return just 3 User objects.

Shall you want to get all combinations of `(User, Address)` tuples, you should add `Address` to your `query(...)` part as well:

```
q = session.query(User, Address).join(Address).all()
for user, address in q:
    print user, address
```

which will return all 6 rows.
If you also wish to return those Users who do not have any address, use `outerjoin` instead of `join`.